# vscode can't find delve even though environment variables are set in launch.json

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch test function",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/checkers/x/checkers/keeper",
            "args": [
           
            ],
            "env": {"GOPATH":"/home/alain/go", "PATH":"/home/alain/go/bin", "GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT": 1}
        }
   
    ]
}
```

The dlv binary is in /home/alain/go/bin and works perfectly. Even outside of that directory it works.

However, when trying to launch debuggin in vscode, I am still getting the error:
Failed to continue "Cannot find delve debugger. Install from https://github.com/go-delve/delve & ensure it is in your Go tools path, "GOPATH/bin" or "PATH"

For reference: I did install delve from https://github.com/go-delve/delve

Comment: Is $GOPATH contained inside of $PATH?